# What does it mean to "take without giving back", when a user is banned?

Tags: support, post-ban, account-suspension

More than once, I stumbled on some SE users who had their accounts temporarily  "blocked"/"banned" (e.g. locked reputation at 1, cannot ask or reply to questions, and maybe some other restrictions).

Although the profile of a "blocked" account has a direct link to some form of Help Center to explain what it means, I'm having a lot of trouble to find said page without finding a "blocked" user (which are hard to come by, luckily).

However, I remember 2 reasons that could push an user into being blocked:

- The first is simple enough: if you don't behave/are too aggressive toward a fellow member.
- The second was something in the line of "keeps taking but never gives back".

I've been trying to search for a meaning for that second reason, but so far I wasn't successful.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

Comment: @Glorfindel Thanks, I will take another look at it and see if it answers my question.

Comment: I agree it's a bit vague and I've yet to see a user banned for this reason. Most of those who'd qualify for this will hit the automatic low-quality question ban anyway (instead of being suspended).

Comment: Good question! It does give me a mild, probably a bit unreasonable (or is it?) fear that I will get a message at some point from a mod on some site saying, "For the past two years, you have done nothing but lurk and soak up the knowledge of other users, never posting or even proposing an edit. I am Suspending you for six months for 'always taking but never giving back'. Once your suspension expires, you will have three weeks to make at least ten posts, failing which, you will be suspended for a whole year.".

Comment: @RobertColumbia My thout exactly, considering I'm asking more questions than giving answers.

Comment: Yes, I had that thought as well, but then I thought that we *already* have the Question Ban for people who do nothing but ask low-quality questions, does it really make sense to have this entirely separate process to ban users who do nothing but post *high-quality* questions, but no answers?

Comment: I guess the simple explanation is "help vampire", and probably that reason exist before automatic ban system. Those who ask good questions are contributing to SE though, because without good questions there won't be good answers.

Comment: The above has an older discussion about this, but the suspension reason you're talking about is rarely employed compared to all the others. It's generally used in cases where the system-based ban on asking questions isn't enabled for a site or isn't working for a specific user. On SO, it's used for rare cases where someone started asking questions before the ban existed, built enough rep by shotgunning questions then to never be eligible for the ban, and continued to dump terrible questions on the site. Moderators manually step in and suspend when that becomes a problem for the site.

Comment: @BradLarson Funny, I wasn't able to find that one when I tried searching by keywords. SE sure has a strange search system.

Comment: @BradLarson : "built enough rep by shotgunning questions then to never be eligible for the ban" - Is there a specific rep threshold at which the ban can never trigger? I've always understood that *rep* is essentially irrelevant to post bans and that the real main metric is upvote/downvote tallies.

Comment: @RobertColumbia - Moderators don't know much about the specific thresholds for the bans (and they change over time), but this is a pattern I've seen. Maybe it isn't reputation so much as a favorable vote balance: they asked 20 questions, 18 of them downvoted, but got lucky with two basic questions that accrued 20+ upvotes each for being common issues. Rinse and repeat. This was a lot more likely in the early days of the site, and without a question ban they could post as many questions as they'd like before they'd get the rare good one.